# Join multiple table and bind into a single Listview using C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, linq, xaml, dynamic-linq

I got three tables to join named Books, Borrowers and Transactions.
The database scheme is as below:

1. Books(BookID,BookName,ISBN);
2. Borrowers(BorrowerID,BorrowerName,BorrowerLevel);
3. Transactions(TransactionID,BorrowerID,BookID,BorrowDate,ReturnDate);

The corresponding class are Book, Borrower and Transaction respectively. Now i would like to select BookID,BookName,BorrowerID,BorrowerName,BorrowDate and ReturnDate from these three tables and to show in a listview having gridview control.
XAML Code :

```
<Grid>
        <ListView Margin="15,57,58,57" Name="borrowedBookList" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding }" KeyDown="borrowedBookList_KeyDown">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="80" Header="Borrower ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=BorrowerID}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="220" Header="Borrower Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=BorrowerName}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="220" Header="Book Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=BookName}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=BorrowDate}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Return Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ReturnDate}"/>
                       </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Now how can i join these tables and assign the result datacontext into borrowedBookList?

Thankyou

Arefin Sami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
borrowedBookList.DataSource =
    from borrower in Borrowers
    join transaction in Transactions
        on borrower.BorrowerID equals transaction.BorrowerID
    join book in Books
        on transaction.BookID equals book.BookID
    select new
    {
        borrower.BorrowerID,
        borrower.BorrowerName,
        book.BookName,
        transaction.BorrowDate,
        transaction.ReturnDate,
    }

borrowedBookList.DataBind();
```

Comment: If my answer is working for you, you should upvote it and click the green arrow to accept it.

Comment: Thom, i have another question. Check it out. i think you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into the hierarchicaldatatemplate class?

Your model or viewmodel would need to contain the respective relationships. From there, the appropriate datatemplate should work nicely.